# How to disable custom hours in mobiscroll?

Tags: jquery, mobile, timepicker, mobiscroll, hour

Currently i am working on a jqm 1.3.1 plus mobiscroll project where the user can make a reservation and pick a date and time via mobiscroll.
I figured out how to disable specific days on the shown wheel:

```
    invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['12/24', '12/25'] },
```

Now i am trying to disable specific hours on the mobiscroll timepicker.

In the documentation there is unfortunately no description on how to achieve this and google couldnt help either.

Someone got an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Invalid hours are not supported at the moment. The feature is tracked here: https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

You can set invalid times (disable times on certain days) with the [invalid](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/datetime#opt-invalid) option starting with the 2.8 release.